# If xlarge layout is not available, will android look into default layouts or large layouts?

Tags: android

Just like in the title.
If there isn't a xlarge layout available, will android look for this in the /layout directory or will it take a step back to /layout-large

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will go to /layout-large because it means at least large.

Comment: yep, just tested it with a nexus 7 (large), it took the layout from /layout-normal instead of default.

Answer (score 1):

If X-large is not available Android will by default look into /layout and not /layout-large. This is the same with other resources like, drawable and values also.

Comment: and what if a layout is only available in xlarge? will 'normal' devices use that layout?